# Enabling a div to overflow side of page

Tags: html, css

I have div that I'm using to form a diagonal line in the background of an HTML file. I want to eventually save this file as a PDF. My issue is that this diagonal line causes the page to resize when a corner reaches page width. I'd like to have it "wrap over the edge of the page". Heres the css for the div. the div located at the bottom of  in the HTML file.

```
.green_line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: solid;
    border-width: 24px;
    border-color: #7cb7b6;
    transform:  rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50px) translateX(50px);
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
.green_line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70vh; /*70vh is the 70% of your current screen try 70% if didn't work*/
    height: 0px;
    border-top: solid;
    border-width: 24px;
    border-color: #7cb7b6;
    transform:  rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50px) translateX(50px);
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Because the `div` is a box. When you rotated it the width somehow become part of the height that when you make the value of the width smaller to match the screen height it won't resize.

> Try adjusting the width and height to match your preference.